# Log4j - log file

Tags: apache, log4j

Does anybody knows how apache log4j handling with streams ?

If it open and close log file for each line or if it simply let open stream and flushing it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't open and close the log file for each line (this would cause too much overhead). Output can be buffered (check the [documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/FileAppender.html)). You could create a custom appender that opens the file for appending for every line though, but what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Actually nothing I only wanted to know how demanding it is for the application.

Comment: Ok. I wouldn't worry about log4j performance overhead for your application too much. On production, you can log only errors for instance. Sometimes you should think a bit about the creation of you log messages (concatenating and serializing objects). But only optimize things like this after you've measured it and found it to be a bottleneck (premature optimization being the root of all evil ;))

Answer (score 2):

One thing springs to mind. If log4j keeps the log file open, log rollover fails, because its file handle still points to the old log file. Opening, writing and closing means log4j would correctly grab the file handle for the new log file.